# fetch properties in preferred language if doesn't exist fetch in default language

Tags: java, java-11

I have food table having number of foods, each food can have specific properties in multiple languages (en, es) like name, description etc. But it is not sure if all of the properties are always present for preferred language of that user, so if they are not present for preferred language we can pick the properties from default language, So that we can be sure that we have data all the time to show on our app,

Here is my PostgreSQL table structure

Food Table:

| food_id | visibility |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | true |

Properties Table:

| property_id | property_code |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | name |
| 2 | description |
| 3 | short desc |

Food Properties Table:

| food_property_id | food_id | property_id | value | language_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | food name in en | en |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | food name in es | es |
| 3 | 1 | 2 | food description in en | en |
| 4 | 1 | 2 | food description in es | es |
| 5 | 1 | 3 | food short desc in en | en |
| 6 | 1 | 3 | food short desc in es | es |

Case 1:

Preferred language - es || Default language - en

All es properties are exists - fetch them all

Result:

Food Properties Table:

| food_property_id | food_id | property_id | value | language id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | food name in es | es |
| 4 | 1 | 2 | food description in es | es |
| 6 | 1 | 3 | food short desc in es | es |

Case 2:

Preferred language - es || Default language - en

Property Id 2 (description) and 3 (short desc) are missing for es, fetch from default language (en)

Food Properties Table:

| food_property_id | food_id | property_id | value | language_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | food name in es | es |
| 3 | 1 | 2 | food description in en | en |
| 5 | 1 | 3 | food short desc in en | en |

I hope the idea is clear to you now: We want to ensure that if specific property does not exists look for that property in default language, I
have to show this food list in app to multiple users with different languages, and it is not guaranteed that all the properties are present for that food. So its ok that we can show properties from default language, just to ensure that all the data on app always looks filled and not empty.

I am using PostgreSQL as database and Java for programming, I am open to solution on both languages, Java preferred as I have used caching layer and filtering properties at that level, I tried a lot but used too many loops to compare each item with each other, so looking for optimized one.

```
public class FoodTest {
    class FoodProperties {
        private String propertyCode;
        private String value;
        private String languageId;
        // getters, setters, constructors
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<FoodProperties> foodProperties = new ArrayList<>();
        FoodProperties p1 = new FoodProperties("1", "food name in en", "en");
        FoodProperties p2 = new FoodProperties("1", "food name in es", "es");
        FoodProperties p3 = new FoodProperties("2", "description in en", "en");
        FoodProperties p4 = new FoodProperties("2", "description in es", "es");
        FoodProperties p5 = new FoodProperties("3", "short desc in en", "en");

        foodProperties.add(p1);
        foodProperties.add(p2);
        foodProperties.add(p3);
        foodProperties.add(p4);
        foodProperties.add(p5);

        String preferredLanguage = "es";
        String defaultLanguage = "en";

        List<FoodProperties> result = new ArrayList<>();
        for (FoodProperties foodProperty : foodProperties) {
            String propertyCode = foodProperty.getPropertyCode();
            Optional<FoodProperties> food = foodProperties.stream()
                    .filter(f -> f.getLanguageId().equals(preferredLanguage)
                            && f.getPropertyCode().equals(propertyCode))
                    .findFirst();
            if (food.isPresent()) {
                result.add(food.get());
            } else {
                Optional<FoodProperties> foodDef = foodProperties.stream()
                        .filter(f -> f.getLanguageId().equals(defaultLanguage)
                                && f.getPropertyCode().equals(propertyCode))
                        .findFirst();
                if (foodDef.isPresent()) {
                    result.add(foodDef.get());
                }
            }
        }
        for (FoodProperties foodPropertiesData : result) {
            System.out.println(foodPropertiesData);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No [tag:java-stream] here.

Answer (score 2):

When selecting just a few rows, you can join the table to itself and keep the data in the first available language

```sql
SELECT 
     coalesce(l1.food_property_id,l2.food_property_id) food_property_id,
     coalesce(l1.food_id, l2.food_id) food_id,    
     coalesce(l1.property_id, l2.property_id) property_id,         
     coalesce(l1.value, l2.value) value,              
     coalesce(l1.language_id, l2.language_id) language_id
FROM food_properties l1
 LEFT JOIN food_properties l2 
  ON l1.food_id = l2.food_id 
  AND l1.property_id = l2.property_id
  AND l2.language_id = 999 --default_language_id
WHERE l1.language_id = 1   --ideal_language_id
```

Note that this approach is simpler if you have two tables, one for the generic attributes and one for the localized attributes.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your solution, it works well, but i am also looking for java optimized solution as I have implemented caching and filtering properties at cache level